# Regex validation for Function with one or two parameter

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex. I want to match for a function with one or two parameters

`[a-z0-9\%\. ]+\(([0-9\.]+|(\[{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(]+\]{1}))([\,]{0,1}([0-9\.]+|\[{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(]+\]{1})){0,1}\)`

This does the job most of time, but it's failing for this case:

`int(123[hello])`

The `123` in between should cause the match to fail, but its not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is your initial use case? are you implementing a JS parser? why do you want to know if a function has precisely 2 args?

Comment: If this is for JS, you should add `$` and `_` to the first range instead of `%`.

Comment: I'm looping through this to validate if it a match, if it's a match, replace it with `0`. This function will later have to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Developer Assistant" add-on for Firefox with the RegExp evaluator, I found that Group 1, 3, and 4 are matching.

> 1 = 123
>
> 3 = hello
>
> 4 = hello

I see that the portion with `int(` is matched by: `[a-z0-9\%\. ]+\(`

Then, `123` is matched by the following, specifically the first portion (whitespace added for clarity)

> (
>
> ```
> [0-9\.]+|
>
>    (\[{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(]+\]{1})
> ```
>
> )

The portion `[hello]` (but not `)`) is matched by the third part of this (the one beginning `\[{1}[`):

> ([\,]{0,1}
>
> ```
> ([0-9\.]+|
>
>     \[{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(]+\]{1}
>
> )
> ```
>
> ){0,1}\)

Comment: I know what is being matched, I need to know why and how to avoid the `123`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
 ([a-z0-9\%\. ]+\((?:[0-9\.]+|\w*(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(?:]+\]))(?:[\,]?(?:[0-9\.]+|\w*\[[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(]+\]))?\))
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jV0aH0)**

**Problem with your code :**

Your code was insufficient to match your requirement .

[image]

I updated the same to :

[image]

Comment: It fails in this condition : `int(213[sdf])`

Comment: @Aashray : Can you explain your requirement ?

Comment: It should not accept `int(213[sdf])`, it should only take `max(213,[sdf])` or `int(213)` or `int([sdf])`

Comment: What about int(sadf)  ??

Answer (score 0):

Just make the coma mandatory:

instead of:

```
[a-z0-9\%\. ]+\(([0-9\.]+|(\[{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(]+\]{1}))([\,]{0,1}([0-9\.]+|\[{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(]+\]{1})){0,1}\)
```

do:

```
[a-z0-9\%\. ]+\(([0-9\.]+|(\[{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(]+\]{1}))([\,]([0-9\.]+|\[{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,\)\(]+\]{1})){0,1}\)
//                                                            here __^
```

You could also do some simplification:

```
[a-z0-9%. ]+\(([0-9.]+|(\[[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,)(]+\]))(,([0-9.]+|\[[a-zA-Z0-9.% ]+[^ ,)(]+\]))?\)
```

For readability:

```
[a-z0-9%. ]+\(
(
    [0-9.]+
    |
    (
        \[[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,)(]+\]
    )
)
(
    ,
    (
        [0-9.]+
        |
        \[[a-zA-Z0-9\.% ]+[^ ,)(]+\]
    )
)?
\)
```